# phpChart not displaying

Tags: php, charts

I'm trying to implement a phpChart Lite (from phpchart.net). I have adjusted all the code but the charts are not displaying. I have a line on the bottom saying that I'm using phpchart but the Chart is not displaying. I have pasted the example from the producers web page, but it's not showing again. Do you have any ideas why it doesn't display?

This is the code I'm using.

```
require_once('phpchart/conf.php'); 
$pc = new C_PhpChartX(array(array(11, 9, 5, 12, 4)),'basic_chart4');
$pc->set_animate(true);
$pc->set_title(array('text'=>'Basic Chart'));
$pc->draw();
```

Is there anything else to configure to display the graph?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the SCRIPTPATH value in conf.php? You should turn on the Developer Tool in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox and see if any errors in javascript console.